# Setting Powershell Execution Policy Through Puppet 3.0

Tags: powershell, puppet

I am trying to set the execution policy for powershell 2.0 using Puppet 3.0 with the following recipe.

```
exec { 'rolesfeatures1':
command => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe Invoke-Command {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned}',
provider => windows,
logoutput => true,
}
```

or

```
exec { 'rolesfeatures1':
command => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe Invoke-Command {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned}',
provider => windows,
logoutput => true,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Puppet but try this:

```
command => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -Command {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned}'
```

or

```
command => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -Command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned}"'
```

Comment: I think it is actually not working for me

exec { 'rolesfeatures1':
  command => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -Command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force}" ',
    provider => windows,
    logoutput => true,
 }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying that i guess using sysnative in replacement of the System32 did fix the issue.

```
exec {'executionpolicy':
        path => 'C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0', #Puppet redirects to SysWOW64 by default
        command => 'Powershell.exe -Command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted}"',
        logoutput => true
        }
```